# iOS ShareKit getting error while sharing video on youtube invalid_client

Tags: ios, youtube, cocoapods, sharekit

We are using [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) for video sharing on youtube, code was working fine but right now getting error

```
<__35-[SHKYouTube authorizationFormShow]_block_invoke SHKYouTube.m:(148)> YouTube authentication finished with error:Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)" UserInfo=0x19452960 {data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f722220 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f63 6c69656e 74220a7d>, json={
error = "invalid_client";
 }}
```

I have created new testing keys from [GoogleConsole](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=flyerly-1211) but still getting this error.

[image]

Using code like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issued has been #fixed, actually  it was API key bug. I found weird issue at Google developer console, when I was creating app type **iOS** it was giving me errors, but when i created the app with type **Others**  keys works fine.

[image: screen shot 2016-02-26 at 9 24 19 pm]

**Steps** 
- Create credentials -then- oAuth Client Id -then- Others
[image]
[image]